# how to convert date format to realtive time format in ionic coming from database

Tags: ionic3

convert date time format to as time_ago format in ionic 3
Currently in our IONIC application we are showing dates in various screens. However, we want to show them as "1 day ago" etc. What is the better way of implementing this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can write a function with this kind of logic and use it everywhere.

```
var currentDate = new Date(); <br />
var currentDay = currentDate.getDate(); 

var yourDate = new Date(your date object or string);<br />
var yourDay = yourDate.getDate();

numberOfDaysAgo = currentDay - YourDay;<br />
console.log(numberOfDaysAgo+' days ago');
```

Comment: how to convert it "time-ago " format i.e coming from database it stored in object  and how to convert it 'time-ago ' format